# Window.GetWindow returns null at design time

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I have spent hours figuring out why Window.GetWindow(this) returns null in my custom control. And, it's only happened at design-time. Run-time is fine. Here is the steps to reproduce the problem:

Step 1: Create a WPF application project in VS2010, targeting .NET 4, named "TestGetWindow"

Step 2: Add a custom control, named MyTextBox. Below is the code.

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public MyTextBox()
    {
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MyTextBox_Loaded);
    }
    void MyTextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Window.GetWindow(this) == null? "Window is NULL!" : "OK");
        DoTrace(this);
    }
}
```

The DoTrace() method is not shown here. It is use to output trace info of visual tree and logic tree, which is copied from [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/43b03840-7168-46dd-8980-963d2156deb7). It outputs trace message to a log file.

Then, use MyTextBox control in MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TestGetWindow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestGetWindow"    
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <local:MyTextBox x:Name="textBox1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="52,62,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now Save All, close MainWindow.xaml designer/editor in Visual Studio, Build project, then reopen MainWindow.xaml. Now check the trace log file, it shows every element has no parent window:

```
========= VISUAL TREE FOR MyTextBox ============
MyTextBox has no window.
Grid has no window.
ContentPresenter has no window.
Grid has no window.
Border has no window.
WindowInstance has no window.
AdornerDecorator has no window.
Grid has no window.
Border has no window.
Border has no window.
DockPanel has no window.
Border has no window.
Grid has no window.
WindowInstance has no window.
Border has no window.
DesignerBackground has no window.
FormDesignerView has no window.
Viewport has no window.
ScrollContentPresenter has no window.
Grid has no window.
ScrollViewer has no window.
Grid has no window.
ContentPresenter has no window.
ContentRoot has no window.
========= LOGICAL TREE FOR MyTextBox ============
MyTextBox has no window.
Grid has no window.
WindowInstance has no window.
Border has no window.
DesignerBackground has no window.
FormDesignerView has no window.
Viewport has no window.
ScrollViewer has no window.
Grid has no window.
ContentRoot has no window.
```

But at run-time, the log shows every elements has a window. What am I missing? Why does Window.GetWindow() always returns null at design-time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! I got it. I should not call Window.GetWindow() at design-time in my custom control. I use the following code to solve my problem:

```
if (System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)) 
{
   return;
}
```